# Why pytest run this unwanted bahavior?

Tags: pytest

I ran "pytest" ((venv) C:\Users\curious\Google Drive\Python\ML\PassportEye>pytest
) from the root directory :

```
├─── setup.py
├───.vscode
├───passporteye
│   ├───mrz
│   │   ├───testdata
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───util
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───PassportEye.egg-info
└───tests
    ├───data
    └───__pycache__
```

and oddly it compute 14 tests, whereas i was expecting only 3 tests. I do not understand why it runs "passporteye\mrz\text.py .....  " since there is not the word "test" in the file nor in the functions inside

```
(venv) C:\Users\curious\Google Drive\Python\ML\PassportEye>pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\curious\Google Drive\Python\ML\PassportEye, configfile: setup.cfg
collected 14 items

passporteye\mrz\text.py .....                                             [ 35%]
passporteye\util\geometry.py ....                                         [ 64%]
passporteye\util\pipeline.py .                                            [ 71%]
tests\mrz_test.py F                                                       [ 78%]
tests\ocr_test.py ..                                                      [ 92%]
tests\pdf_extraction_test.py .                                            [100%]

=================================== FAILURES =================================== 
________________________ test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream _________________________ 

    def test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream():
        for fn, test_fn in [('./tests/data/passport-td3.jpg', assert_td3_jpg),   
                            ('./tests/data/passport-td3.png', assert_td3_png),   
                            ('./tests/data/passport-td2.jpg', assert_td2_jpg),   
                            ('./tests/data/passport-td2.png', assert_td2_png),
                           ]:
            for as_stream in [True, False]:
>               test_fn(read_img(fn, as_stream=as_stream))

tests\mrz_test.py:23:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  

mrz = MRZ(TD3[98], L898902C3, ANNAKMARIAK   K K X X, ERIKSSON, F, 740812)

    def assert_td3_jpg(mrz):
        assert mrz is not None
        assert mrz.mrz_type == 'TD3'
        assert mrz.valid_score >= 62  # Can be 100 on some Tesseract installations
        assert mrz.type == 'P<'
        assert mrz.country == 'UTO'
        assert mrz.number == 'L898902C3'
        assert mrz.date_of_birth == '740812'
        assert mrz.expiration_date == '120415'
        assert mrz.nationality == 'UTO'
        assert mrz.sex == 'F'
>       assert mrz.names == 'ANNA MARIA'
E       AssertionError: assert 'ANNAKMARIAK   K K X X' == 'ANNA MARIA'
E         - ANNA MARIA
E         + ANNAKMARIAK   K K X X

tests\mrz_test.py:36: AssertionError
=============================== warnings summary =============================== 
..\example\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:2
  c:\users\curious\google drive\python\ml\example\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:2: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of 
importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp, sys, os

tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream
  c:\users\curious\google drive\python\ml\example\venv\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py:226: DeprecationWarning: Converting `np.inexact` or `np.floating` to a dtype is deprecated. The current result is `float64` which is not strictly correct.
    dtypeobj_out = np.dtype(dtype)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================ 
FAILED tests/mrz_test.py::test_td2_td3_stream_nonstream - AssertionError: asse...
================== 1 failed, 13 passed, 10 warnings in 17.21s ==================
```

Edit (setup.cfg):

```
[egg_info]
tag_build =
tag_svn_revision = false

[tool:pytest]
addopts = --ignore=setup.py --ignore=build --ignore=dist --doctest-modules
norecursedirs=*.egg
```

Comment: You don't have `python_files` set in your `config.cfg`?

Comment: Thanks! I completed with an edit with the targeted file. I am not used to this kind of .cfg file but your clever remark made me point the "doctest-modules". I will gather informations about that parameter.

Comment: Yes, with `doctest-modules` it will check all Python files for doc tests - hadn't thought about this. So it looks like this has been done intentionally.